# Problems with falcon API healthcheck

Tags: docker, falcon

I have a following falcon API in python:

```py
import falcon

class Ping:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_OK


app = application = falcon.App()

app.add_route("/exp_costs/v1/healthcheck", Ping())
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.10


COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt update && \
    pip install gunicorn && \
    pip install --python --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . /app


EXPOSE 8000
USER nobody:nogroup
WORKDIR /app

# Command to run your Falcon API (adjust as needed)
CMD ["gunicorn", "app", "--bind", ":8000"]
```

My steps:

1. `sudo docker build -t costs_expedice .`
2. `sudo docker run -it -p 8099:80 costs_expedice`

and I can see this in the terminal:

[image]

3. `wget http://localhost:8099//exp_costs/v1/healthcheck`

but I got repeated message:

`--2023-08-29 14:17:36--  http://localhost:8099//exp_costs/v1/healthcheck Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8099... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers. Retrying.`

Whats the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your Dockerfile exposes 8000 and sets it as gunicorn bind port, but your docker run command binds to port 80 of container and your `wget` command has a typo with an extra "/" after port spec of 8099. Then your `CMD` is also malformed that gunicorn expects an option of the form `<module>:<object>` like `main:app` if your module is named as `main.py`. You can check options of gunicorn with `gunicorn --help` to refine your `CMD` further.